# E-prime: Inline script to present sounds from a text file

Tags: software, hearing

I am trying to build an experiment that: (1) present Instructions, (2) plays a list of sounds from a text file and (3) says Goodbye. I have problem on (2) which for the moment is built with an inline script object. I cannot hear any sounds when I run the experiment. The sound files (22KHz, 24bit, MONO) are located on the same folder as the experiment file. I am using E-prime 2.0 Professional. 
I would be grateful to you if you could give me some advice.

** The Text File **

```
Weight  Nested  Procedure   Sound
1       BlockProc   S2B.wav
1       BlockProc   S1B.wav
```

** The inline code **

```
BlockList.LoadMethod = ebLoadMethodFile
BlockList.Filename = "sounds.txt"
BlockList.Load
BlockList.Reset
Set BlockList.TerminateCondition = Cycles(1)
Set BlockList.ResetCondition = Samples(BlockList.Deletion.Count)
```

I have also attached a print screen of the Experiment & text file.
Thank you very much for your time. Any help will be very much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Questions on E-Prime seem to more often not get answers here... so perhaps use their technical support since you have a paid license. (I changed your tags because your question is not about the design of your experiment, but rather its implementation in software.)

Comment: See if you can hear anything using their SoundTester: https://support.pstnet.com/hc/en-us/articles/229362847-INFO-Use-of-SoundTester-to-determine-machine-compatibility-with-ASIO-or-Core-Audio-WASAPI-18834-

Comment: @Fizz I tried SoundTester and it works fine, I also tried another experiment with movie+sound and there was no problem. Anyway, thank you for your assistance, and I hope to resolve the issue with the E-prime support.